# Is there a Xamarin.Mac Full Framework which targets .net Framework 4.6.1 or higher?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, xamarin.mac

I am just playing around with Visual Studio 2017 on Mac. I created a small Cocoa application that works fine. I now want to reference another library that is based on .net Standard 2.0 and uses the AWS SDK.
Using the modern Xamarin.Mac this does not work because `AWSSDK` pulls in `PCLCrypto` and `Xamarin.iOS` so I switched my project to the full framework.
When I now open the project properties, the version level of the Xamarin.Mac Full framework is reported as .net 4.5.1 which isn't compatible with .net Standard 2.0

Is this as it should be, and is it possible to target a higher version instead?

## Followup 1

I got it to work with a workaround that shows some errors of unreferenced packages and require some ugly plumbing. Here is what I did:

Step 1:

Removed the `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v2.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>` and `<TargetFrameworkIdentifier>Xamarin.Mac</TargetFrameworkIdentifier>` lines from the first `PropertyGroup` in the `.csproj`

Step 2:

Added the following to the `.csproj` to its first `PropertyGroup`:

```
<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
<UseXamMacFullFramework>True</UseXamMacFullFramework>
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

Step 3:

Reloaded the project in VS 2017

Step 4: Added my .net Standard Library and all its Nuget packages it depends on.

This is ugly, and it will show some `System.*` references as not existing in VS 2017, but it compiles and runs. It also doesn't seem to correctly pull in transitive dependencies, thus you have to add every dependency to the main project yourself.

This is ugly but at least it works for me. I hope there is a better way...

Comment: The target frameworks are well documented https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/mac/platform/target-framework In your case, you can only use Xamarin.Mac Full as your target due to the dependencies (equivalent to what you manually edited).

Comment: This does not answer my question. I want to know why Visual Studio detects my installed Mono as .net 4.5 compliant when it can do 4.7.1 and why it states it can’t find `System`, `System.Core` and `Xamarin.Mac` when I force it to target 4.7.1, despite compiling and running fine without any errors.

Comment: 1) "Visual Studio detects my installed Mono as .net 4.5 compliant when it can do 4.7.1" does not happen on my machine, where VS for Mac says "Xamarin.Mac Full: .NET Framework 4.7.1". 2) "it states it can’t find System, System.Core and Xamarin.Mac when I force it to target 4.7.1" can be reproduced though, which usually people report to Microsoft as bug, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/report-a-problem

Comment: Maybe on my installation there is some version clash because I had the old Xamarin Studio installed before it became Visual Studio, I'll look into this. for the second thing which is more annoying to me (as I can always "force" the correct .net version by editing the csproj directly) I'm going to report this to MS.